# firebase how to identify users who have just closed the app but didn't log out

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, local-storage, ionic4, firebaseui

I am using firebaseui phone authentication to log in users. I want to redirect new users to the 'details' page to get some details about them and when the user comes for the second time assuming he has submitted all details redirect to the 'items' page.

my code

```
this.afauth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.

        if(user.metadata.creationTime == user.metadata.lastSignInTime) {
          console.log("new user") 
        }

        else {
          console.log("user logged in after log out")
        }


      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
```

In this code, I can identify
1. new users
2. The user who logged in after logging out

But I can't identify users who didn't log out from the app (just closed the app).
I also tried local storage. If values are set the redirect to the 'items' page and if the value is null redirect to the 'details' page. But there are two problems with this approach

1. If the user changes his device (I am building a hybrid app) then he will be redirected to the details page.
2. When the user logs out, the storage value becomes null and redirects to the details page.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a very difficult problem, since the user might leave the app, and if it doesn't have internet access at that time, the record of their leaving might be lost forever.  Also, if the user uninstalls the app, you'd never know.  I'd suggesting finding a different way to track what you want, since sign-in status isn't a very reliable indicator of what the user is actually doing in your app.

Comment: Can you suggest any indication for acheieving this.